# Table of contents in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I have a Word document with different parts (Part-1, Part-2, etc,.) and different sections in each part. 
I just want to create a Automatic table of contents in the following manner

```
PART 1 – XXXXX  1-30
SECTION I - XXXXX   2
SECTION II - XXXXX  12
SECTION III. XXXXXX 23
PART 2 - XXXXX  31-56
SECTION IV – XXXXX  32
PART 3 – XXXXX  57-80
SECTION V – XXXXX   60
```

Comment: what you've tried? what you could achieve? what doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I have inserted table of contents from the references tab. when I update it is showing that the part-1 on a particular page only (i,e like on page 1). but I want to indicate the entire pages of part-1 as (1-30) and the remaining sections as individual page numbers as occurred. I have tried to modify the table of contents in the settings and also tried to create a new style but failed to indicate whole part-1 page numbers at once.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/2010-toc-show-both-begin-and-end-page-numbers/0f3a36f1-0b1e-4171-8e2e-51a037008c10

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it by using `TC` fields for each part heading.

First, make sure that paragraph marks and other hidden symbols are visible. If they aren't, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>. For this to work, there also has to be a section break before each numbered part in your document.

1. Select and copy the paragraph for the first part heading.
2. Place the cursor at the end of the paragraph, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. Inside the braces (`{}`), type `TC`, a space, a pair of quotation marks, and then `\l 1 \n`. Inside the quotation marks, paste the heading text that you copied. The field definition should look something like this:

   `{ TC "Part 1 – XXXXX" \l 1 \n }`

   The `\n` switch at the end suppresses the page number in the TOC entry that is generated for the part heading; in the next steps, you'll make the page numbers part of the `TC` field definition itself.
3. Place the cursor right before the end quotation mark (that is, right after the `XXXXX`), and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. Inside the braces, type `PAGE`. This inserts the number of the part's first page. After the closing brace for this new `PAGE` field, type a dash.
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. Inside the braces, type `=` followed by a space.
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. Inside the braces, type `PAGE`. After the closing brace for this new `PAGE` field, type `+`.
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. Inside the braces, type `SECTIONPAGES`. After the closing brace for this new `SECTIONPAGES` field, type `-1`.

   Steps 5–7 create a formula that takes the number of the part's first page and adds the total number of pages in the section for that part, subtracting 1 to arrive at the number of the last page of that part.

   The final field definition should look like this:

   `{ TC "PART 1 – XXXXX   { PAGE }–{ = { PAGE }+{ SECTIONPAGES }-1 }" \l 1 \n }`
8. Repeat steps 1–7 for all other part headings in your doc.

You now have to insert a custom TOC where the entries for the part headings are generated by using your `TC` fields and the entries for the other headings are generated by using styles.

1. On the **References** tab, in the **Table of Contents** group, click **Table of Contents** > **Custom Table of Contents**.
2. Click **Options**, and then, in the list of styles under the **Styles** check box, delete the **1** next to **Heading 1** (or whatever style you're using for part headings). Select the **Table entry fields** check box.

You'll end up with something like this.

[image: TOC with page ranges for part headings]

I did have some issues with the tab space in the finished TOC. Manually reapplying the **TOC1** paragraph style to all the entries for part headings sorted this out though.

If you want the page numbers to be separated from the heading text by a simple space instead of a tab space, in step 3 of the first procedure, press the spacebar instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Then, in the **Table of Contents** dialog box, clear the **Right align page numbers** check box. You'll end up with something like this:

[image: TOC with page ranges for part headings, version 2]

Finally, if you're proficient in Word fields, you can use `STYLEREF` fields inside the `TC` field to automatically pull in the part number and title instead of manually typing them. That way, once you've set up the `TC` field for the first part heading, you can just copy and paste it for all the others. In this case, however, the `TC` field can't be in the same paragraph as the heading itself; it has to be somewhere after it. For example, I used the **Heading 1** style for part headings and ended up with this:

`{ TC "{ STYLEREF "Heading 1" \n } { STYLEREF "Heading 1" } { PAGE }–{ = { PAGE }+{ SECTIONPAGES }-1 }" \l 1 \n }`

(Because the space+dash after the part number was part of the autonumbering definition, I didn't need to manually type it between the two `STYLEREF` fields.)